# Layout in Joomla Custom Module

Tags: joomla3.0, bootstrap-grid

I am using a Bootstrap enabled Joomla template and I am trying to use Bootstrap in a custom HTML module and when i view the outcome, the layout is not right. When I test the code on W3Schools it works perfect. My template has got the reference to the bootstrap Javascript and the CSS too so I dont know what the problem is.

Here is what it should look like:

[image: what it should look like]

And here is what it looks like:

[image: what it looks like]

Iv tried to test it on a code tester and on a bootstrap emulator it works perfect but in Joomla it is not.

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: center; color: #999999; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">
      Ons verwelkom jonk en oud, enkellopend, getroud, geskei, weduwee, wewenaar, gay, ryk, arm, Afrikaanses, Engelse, skreeuende babas, woelige toddlers, moeilike tieners, twyfelaars, liberales, fundamentaliste, soekers, die wat mooi sing en die wat vals sing, die wat lanklaas in die kerk was en die wat nie hou van kerk nie... en VIR JOU. By ons gemeente is elkeen iemand!
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="width: 301px;">
      <a href="index.php/preke-sermons"><img class="effectck-honey" title="Preke::Luister na preke / Listen to sermons." src="http://www.ngkerktableview.co.za/images/cross.png" alt="" width="251" height="165" /></a>    
    </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="width: 301px;">
      <a href="index.php/bedieninge"><img class="effectck-honey" title="Bedieninge::Sien ons Bedienings / See our Ministries." src="http://www.ngkerktableview.co.za/images/bible.png" alt="" width="251" height="165" /></a>   
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: center; color: #999999; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">
      We welcome young and old, single, married, divorced, widow, widower, gay, rich, poor, Afrikaans, English, crying babies, restless toddlers, difficult teenagers, doubters, liberals, fundamentalists, seekers, those that can sing and those who can't, those that who haven't been to church in a while and those who don't like church... AND YOU. In our congregation everyone is someone!    
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that your Joomla template uses Bootstrap 3 and not Bootstrap 2. If you aren't sure how to do this, try changing the class of 'col-sm-6' to 'span6' and see if this helps.

[More about Bootstrap 2.3 scaffolding and CSS here](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)

Good luck!